# Making a port HIGH in the intel 8051 microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, 8051, intel

Does an instruction like this:
**MOV P1.0, #1**
makes the port P1 bit 0 High so i can drive an LED for example, or it just makes it FLOAT so i can use an external circuitry to light the LED.
If so, does this mean that we can't output a "real" HIGH to the ports?

Comment: Surely this is answered in the datasheet!

Comment: Please edit your question and add a link to the datasheet.

Answer (score 4):

The 8051 (original 'flavors') does not output a '1' with much drive capability. It is better to connect your LED + resistor from the output to Vdd and drive the pin low to turn the LED on. You could also add a pull-up to Vdd and shunt the LED, but that wastes power.

Edit: as per request, below is the i8051 I/O structure from the [MCS-51 manual](http://web.mit.edu/6.115/www/document/8051.pdf).

[image]

The strength of the pull-ups varies according to the type, but can be as high as 30mA nominal for the brief strong pull-up, and tens or hundreds of uA for the weak.

Comment: I know that microcontrollers "generally" can't drive LED's this way, i just want to know if the microcontroller pin acts as a FLOAT or HIGH if i used the instruction MOV P1.0, #1.

Comment: It is weakly pulled to a high with a brief stronger pulse to high to drive external capacitance. So the answer is not so simple.

Comment: If it can't drive, then it can usually not sink current either. Just put a transistor/buffer in between the MCU and the LED(s).

Comment: @Lundin In this case, the output is quite capable of sinking enough current to drive a modern LED. The p-channel drive is made deliberately weak.

Answer (score 1):

It depends in the output pin driver.

- If it is an Open-Drain type then the pin can either float or tied to ground.
- If it is a Push-Pull then it is either tied to VCC or ground.

At many microcontrollers this can be configured so you should cehck the datasheet about the default setup.

Comment: Actually it is neither open drain nor push-pull. The 8051 uses pseudo-bidirectional outputs.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany That is an Open-Drain type with internal pull-ups?

Comment: It's even a bit more convoluted- there is a weak pull-up MOSFET and a stronger MOSFET in parallel that is pulsed on during low-to-high transistions to quickly charge capacitive loads.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I have checked an image in one of your [answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/155854/can-we-use-8051-pin-as-input-and-output-at-a-time), but I will do further research then. Do you have any good reference, where did you find that picture for example?

Comment: Someone else edited that into my answer and it is a simplified view. I've added a more complete schematic and a link to the original data to my answer here.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thank you I appreciate you efforts.